# Elixir: dynamic parameter in use statement

Tags: module, initialization, elixir

How could I pass `adapter` parameter dynamically to Nebulex.Cache module initialization?

```
defmodule MyApp.RedisCache do    
  use Nebulex.Cache,
      otp_app: :nebulex,
      adapter: if true do NebulexRedisAdapter else Nebulex.Adapters.Nil end
end
```

Comment: That should work exactly as you have written. Maybe with additional parens around the `if`, but it seems as a perfectly valid code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to move the conditional one level up.

```rb
defmodule MyApp.RedisCache do    
  if true do
    use Nebulex.Cache,
      otp_app: :nebulex,
      adapter: NebulexRedisAdapter
  else
    use Nebulex.Cache,
      otp_app: :nebulex,
      adapter: Nebulex.Adapters.Nil
  end
  ...
end
```

Another way would be to create a private macro with a parameter, or, alternatively, create a module attribute storing the `adapter` and pass it to `use` (assuming `Nebulex.Cache` does [`Macro.expand/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#expand/2) arguments in the `__CALLER__` context.)

---

The reason is that the macro receives the AST, so what will `__using__/1` receive, is `quote do: if ....` which won’t be even attempted to compile at the first compilation stage.

---

The below code might shed a light on how the AST is passed between calls and what `Macro.expand/2` does.

```rb
defmodule M do
  @param if(true, do: M1, else: M2)

  defmacrop t1(arg: args) do
    IO.inspect(args, label: "#1")
  end
  defmacrop t2(arg: args) do
    IO.inspect(Macro.expand(args, __CALLER__), label: "#2")
  end

  def test do
    t1(arg: if(true, do: M1, else: M2))
    t2(arg: if(true, do: M1, else: M2))
    t1(arg: @param)
    t2(arg: @param)
  end
end
```

It results in:

```
#1: {:if, [line: 19],
 ...
#2: {:case, [optimize_boolean: true],
 ...
#1: {:@, [line: 21], [{:param, [line: 21], nil}]}
#2: M1
```

Note, that `if` was expanded to `case`, and the module attribute was not expanded unless the explicit `Macro.expand/2` was called on it.